# Importance of Glueball

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, gluons

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glueball),

> "In particle physics, a glueball (also gluonium, gluon-ball) is a hypothetical composite particle.[1] It consists solely of gluon particles, without valence quarks. Such a state is possible because gluons carry color charge and experience the strong interaction between themselves. Glueballs are extremely difficult to identify in particle accelerators, because they mix with ordinary meson states.[2]"

If Glueball exists, what happens as an effect?

Comment: This seems to be a rather broad question. Could you narrow down the area of what it is about the glueball's existence that you'd like to know, rather than all possible thing?

Answer (score 2):

> If Glueball exists, what happens as an effect?

Glue balls should exist as lattice QCD, which is a succesful tool for calculating strong interactions, (as for example it almost fits  the [masses of the resonances,](http://www.durr.itp.unibe.ch/talk_09_psi.pdf) (page 2) ) predicts and gives ranges for finding them.

A glueball candidate should appear as a resonance in the invariant masses of particles to which it will decay, which are the same particles to which the usual resonances decay, so it is hard to  think of a way to separate the glue balls from normal resonances. [This article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.0589) has a review of possibilities.

> There have been considerable efforts to identify glueballs
>   experimentally. The aim is at first to establish the lightest qq_bar  nonets in the spectrum; then, the appearance of extra states
>   could hint towards a glueball. More directly, one looks for an
>   enhanced production of a glueball candidate in "gluon rich" processes but a suppression in γγ reactions.

It goes on with examples.

Comment: Thank you for your explain. I understand some theory predicts existence of glue balls. Then what kind of phenomenon is an effect of existence? Please answers shortly.

Comment: thephenomenon is called resonances, see my answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64862/resonances-in-high-energy-physics . They look like the  usual resonances so it is not easy to find them, as stated in the link I give.