# Resourcs on learning about 2-body resources

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, bosons, mesons, baryons

As a part of my Particle Physics Course, I will need to give a talk on 2-body resonances - What are they? Some examples like (Ψ), Z boson and significance of those discoveries. I am looking for suggestions on good resources to learn more about these as it is getting little difficult to obtain them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting any responses because this is a topic that is included in all courses implicitly, at all levels of courses. Searching on Google I [found this specific](https://www.cpp.edu/~pbsiegel/phy40413/lectures/lecture10.pdf) for resonances, which of course includes two body resonances, since they are the simpler to write down mathematically:

The answer of [mine here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64862/resonances-in-high-energy-physics) , may help.