# Are there any mesons with one charm antiquark?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quarks, mesons

Is there a meson with one charm antiquark, $\bar{c}$, so that $C=-1$? Can they exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The lightest examples are the [D mesons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_meson) which have a single $c$ or $\bar c$.

Comment: DJones , + They exists in resonances, before decaying .  see this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64862/resonances-in-high-energy-physics