# Derivation of mass-lifetime relation in particle physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, virtual-particles, half-life

How is the inverse relation between the lifetime and mass of a virtual particle derived?

For example, it is said that the strong force is short range because its force carrier is massive, and hence has a short lifetime, and hence cannot travel far.

Is this relation actually derived anywhere or is there just a tradition?

---

My own tentative (proposed) conclusions so far.

1. real particles do not have an inverse relation between lifetime and mass. For example, in the standard model the proton is stable, but in SU(5) it has a finite lifetime.
2. virtual particles have a questionable ontology, and only exist within Feynman diagrams calculations. For example, Schwinger theory works with the fields and has no virtual particles.
3. the uncertainty principle would suggest that the lifetime of a particle of a given mass should be at least a given time, rather than at most. The argument from the uncertainty principle is erroneous.
4. the above conclusions suggest that it is merely a cosmic coincidence that the uncertainty relation argument produces any correct results here.
5. The Fermi Golden Rule seems to be the only other viable alternative. This has more of the right feel, being based on the rate at which the coefficients of an expansion in a non stationary eigen basis change over time. However, all it derives is the initial rate of change for a step change in the potential. Hence, the result is only valid as determining a rate of transition if there is a virtual continuum of states. When this condition is satisfied in practical optics, the conclusions do indeed work.

Comment: A rotation is a circle. Stretching it in time creates a sine wave. Real particles are waves. Virtual particles are circles. They don't move in time, but exist for one period of oscillation of their wave function.

Comment: A pair of virtual particles can be seen as a closed loop in spacetime, but in this context, my question is how is the diameter of the loop determined?

Comment: Loops usually are higher order, not what I mean. I am saying the wavefunction of a single virtual particle is not a function of time. Imagine a rotating wheel that moves along its axis. A point on the wheel has a spiral trajectory. It is a wavefunction of a real particle moving in time. After 1 period of oscillations the function position has advanced in time like a spiral. Virtual particles stay in time. The wheel rotates, but doesn't move along the axis of time. After 1 period of oscillations the function is at the same point in time like a circle. The "diameter" is 1 period of oscillations.

Comment: Regarding your actual question, I've seen it before on this site. Have you tried searching?

Comment: Yes, I have searched and not just on stack exchange. The closest I have to answer so far is https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/41890/200377 which I interpret as meaning that the lifetime of the particle cannot be derived from the uncertainty relation. But, this does not answer the question of how the lifetimes are derived. I originally thought this was straight forward enough, but the more I look at the mathematics, the less I can find justification for the conclusions. The answer is probably - by using 1st order approximation from perturbation theory.

Comment: I've heard this discussed in relation to the [Yukawa potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_potential) being the time independent spherically symmetric solution to the [Klein Gordon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation) equation. I'm unclear how to flesh this into an answer currently though.

Comment: jacob1729 I am not sure where this will go, but it's something I can chase, thanks.