# Equivalence of $d$ dimensional quantum system to $d+1$ dimension stats system

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, temperature, time, wick-rotation

> " There are close analogies between quantum field
>   theories in d dimensions and classical statistical mechanics in d + 1."

What does this statement imply and from where does this extra dimension come from? Is it because we introduce imaginary time, $t = -i\tau$ ?

Comment: If the statement is talking about Wick rotation, then probably it's because classical statistical mechanics, being the study of equilibria, is not time-dependent (i.e. time doesn't really appear as a variable), so you need an extra spatial dimension to capture the full dimensionality of a quantum system.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87306/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Where does this quote come from?

Comment: Chap 3 Atland and Simon's field theory